# How many Theme licenses to buy on 1 Magento 2.x install with 3 websites/stores/storefronts each running on a separate domain?

Tags: theme, license

```
Magento 2.4.2
Porto theme
```

I am setting up a new project on Magento 2.4.2 which will have 1 Magento installation running on a dummy (not used in the project at all) domain with 3 additional websites/stores/storefronts each set up on a different unique domain.

I want to everything by the book so I was searching how many Porto licenses I need to buy and I came across this article on Porto's website:

https://smartwave.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/12000052418--9-theme-forest-license-policy-

Is it correct then that if we have the primary domain which will not be a site at all and then the 3 addon domains each with its own website/store/storefront, that we need 3 licenses?

Answer (score 0):

I got a reply from Smartwave Porto and the answer is - **it is 1 license per each domain**:

*"A single license is applied to use for one domain. For multiple domains, please kindly buy multiple licenses. For example, you have two domains using Porto, then you please buy Porto twice."*